# Solving Trigonometric

Tags: trigonometry

**Question**

Convert $\theta = -\frac{2a\pi }{3}$ rad to degrees form where $a$ is a natural number. Hence, find
the smallest value of $$ if $$ lies in the second quadrant.

I trying to solve ...
$$\theta = -\frac{2a\pi }{3}$$
I know $\pi$ rad $=180^{\circ}$
so $1$ rad $=\frac{180}{\pi}$
then

$$\theta = -\frac{2a\pi }{3}\times\frac{180}{\pi}=-120a^{\circ} $$

lies in the second quadrant then $$ lies in the second quadrant equal to $180^{\circ}-\theta$ ???

I dont know how to start to get  $$ in second quadrant. May you help me to solve this question?

Thank you so much.

Comment: -120a should lie between 90 and 180

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the same position in the unit circle if you add multiples of $360^\circ$. Second quadrant means angles between $90^\circ$ and  $180^\circ$. So take a look at several $a$ values: $a=0$ means $\theta=0$, $a=1$ means $\theta=-120\to -120+360=240$. None of these are in the second quadrant. For $a=2$, $\theta=-240\to -240+360=120$. This is the right answer

Comment: why θ=−120→−120+360 ??? how you get +360??  @andrei

Comment: 180 degrees is half a circle, 360 is a full circle rotation. You want to get the equivalent angle. If you think about the periodicity of $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions, the period is $2\pi$ radians, which is $360^\circ$.